# How to interpret $\langle (f(u))', v \rangle = \langle f'(u)u', v \rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

We know that if $u$ has a weak derivative $u'$, and if $f \in C^1$ with $f'$ bounded then $(f(u))'= f'(u)u'$.

But how interpret the duality pairing
$$\langle (f(u))', v \rangle = \langle f'(u)u', v \rangle?$$

Is it equal to $\langle u', f'(u)v \rangle$. I don't think so, I think we need smoothness to say so. But is there any way to write the equality above as one involving the weak derivative $u'$?

Let us for example here take the duality pairing of $H^{-1}$ and $H^1$.

Comment: You have that $(f(u))'$ and $f'(u)u'$ are the same element of $H^1$, in particular they agree almost everywhere. So, $u'=(f(u))'/f'(u)$ assuming $f'(u)\ne 0$ a.e. Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah I guess there is nothing more we can say.